# Program To find frequency of numbers in a giver array

Tags: java, arrays

This is not really a question pointing to any error but asking for a improvement over a program written in java.
This is a very simple program to find the number of occurrences of a particular integer in a given array of integers.

This program is ,however, working just fine but I want to know if any improvement can be done over this program to save time or memory.

Here is the program:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Logix {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int arr[] = { 10, 9, 8, 7, 3, 10, 8, 1, 8, 3, 1, 1 };
    int cnt = 0, count = 1;
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(12);
    int currntN = arr[cnt];

    outer:while (cnt != arr.length) {
        if(!map.isEmpty()){
            if(map.containsKey(arr[cnt])){
                cnt++;
                continue outer;
            }
            currntN = arr[cnt];
            count=1;
        }
        for (int i = cnt + 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (currntN == arr[i]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        cnt++;
        map.put(currntN, count);
    }

    System.out.println(map);
}
}
```

This is a very basic beginner level program.
I hope to know that there CAN be some improvements done.
Thank You

Comment: IMO, this question is better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for a code review.

Comment: You can do it in one pass of `arr`. Also, ditch that nasty break to a label.

Comment: @Raedwald "Belongs on Code Review" or "is a code review request" is not a valid close reason. Please see the section "What you should not do" in [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow Users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Code reviews are off topic here. Whether a particular request for a code review is on topic somewhere else is a different matter.

Comment: @Raedwald Regardless of whether code reviews are off-topic or not, "is a code review" is still not a valid close reason.

Comment: @Raedwald Depends how you define "Code Review". Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions, so whilst a general Code Review is probably too broad, a focused review of a properly scoped aspect of some piece of code certainly can be.

Comment: @Bathsheba:  If you could show how?

Answer (score -1):

I see that you have used two loops in your solution. Solution for this problem can be optimized to use only a single loop.

Here is the code snippet with essential comments. I hope it will help you understand the concept:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    int[] arr = {10,9,8,7,10,9,8,7,10,9};
    calculateFrequency(arr);
}

public static void calculateFrequency(final int[] numberList) {
    /* Calculate Frequency */
    Map<Integer,Integer> cnts = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberList.length; i++) {
        /* Update Counts */
        cnts.put(numberList[i],cnts.containsKey(numberList[i]) ? cnts.get(numberList[i]) + 1 : 1);
    }

    /* Print Values */
    System.out.println(cnts);
}
```

If you want to iterate the map then you can do it as follows:

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : cnts.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Number = " + entry.getKey() + ", Frequency = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Output:

```
Number = 7, Frequency = 2
Number = 8, Frequency = 2
Number = 9, Frequency = 3
Number = 10, Frequency = 3
```

Comment: I believe this is a good answer, because you solve the issue of the double loop (O(n^2)) with a single loop (O(n), I believe.)

On that note, if we are going for "maximum efficiency", using ints rather than doubles would be preferable. That is so nit-picky, though, that I sort of hate myself for saying ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer

Comment: Why is this down-voted? @Harshvarshan Request you to please accept the answer and up-vote it if it helped you.

Answer (score -4):

```
Arrays.sort(arr);
 for(int i=0;i<arr.length;)
                {
                    count=1;
                    for(index=i+1;index<arr.length;index++)
                    {
                        if(arr[i]==arr[index])
                        {
                            count++;
                        }
                        else{

                            break;
                        }


                    }
                    System.out.println("   "+arr[i]+ "   "+count);
                    i+=count;

Hope my code provide answer to your problem.Happy coding.
```

Comment: Absolutely vulgar. Why the second loop?

Comment: Please include the comments and explain why you think this solution is better.

Comment: Because you are still using two for-loops, the time complexity is still O(n^2). While I could argue that your code is cleaner, the question dealt with improving time / memory.